# Getting invalid bind variable in SQL developer

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can i create a trigger named ProductMaint that update Quantity in my Inventory after selling and updating order table .Unique Product is found in both order placed and Inventory by unifying two rows i.e Manufacturer and product name . How can i trigger it without any error ??
I have done it but error is prompting invalid bind variable

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ProductMaint
  AFTER INSERT ON Orders
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN(NEW.Qty >0)
  BEGIN
  UPDATE Products
  SET Qtyonhand = Qtyonhand - :NEW.Qty
  WHERE Products.Mfr =Orders.Mfr
  AND Products.Product =Orders.Product;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:New.Qtyonhand);    

 END;
 /
```

Comment: insert a space between when and ( ?

Comment: its complied and now when i make an order update through procedure its is saying me : 
Error report -
ORA-04098: trigger 'S304.PRODUCTMAINT' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SET DEFINE OFF` which turns off substitution of variables.
Use `Run script (F5)` command/icon to execute the whole script.

```
  SET DEFINE OFF;
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ProductMaint
  AFTER INSERT ON Orders
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN(NEW.Qty >0)
  BEGIN
  UPDATE Products
  SET Qtyonhand = Qtyonhand - :NEW.Qty
  WHERE Products.Mfr =Orders.Mfr
  AND Products.Product =Orders.Product;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:New.Qtyonhand);    

 END;
 /
```

Comment: Hie thanks for replying . after compling it is prompting me to enter binds and then shows me invalid bind variable.